# Download an excel file saved on flask server

Tags: excel, reactjs, flask, download

I have a flask app that has an existing xlsx file in the downloads folder. I am trying to make the front-end download the excel file on a button click. As of right now, my flask server is accessing the file correctly, but sending it as nonsensical string data in the response. I'm assuming I need to use some library to parse the data into an excel workbook and then download it, but I'm having trouble finding answers. 
Here is the flask code:

```
    @app.route('/download')
    @handle_errors
    def downloadFile():
        filename = request.args.get('filename')
        uploadPath = sys.path[0] + '\\workflow\\downloads'
        return send_file(uploadPath + '\\' + filename, as_attachment=True)
```

Here is the front end react code:

```
    getFile = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.persist();
        const filename = e.target.getAttribute('name');
        axios
          .get(`http://localhost:5000/download?filename=${filename}`)
          .then((data) => {
            console.log('this is data: ', data);
            console.log('Completed: download');
          })
          .catch(() => {
            console.log('We were not able to complete your request.');
          });
      };
```

Comment: What is the desired behaviour? Do you want to use the file contents on the front-end somehow? Or do you want the user to download the file on their computer "as is"?

Answer (score 1):

Your server already seems to be sending a blob. So in the frontend, do:

- use `URL.createObjectURL` and create url object from response.data
- create an anchor tag on the fly and associate the url object to the `href`
- call `click()` which will download the file on client
- remove the anchor tag

**Code snippet**

```js
getFile = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.persist();
    const filename = e.target.getAttribute('name');
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:5000/download?filename=${filename}`)
      .then((data) => {
        console.log('this is data: ', data.data);
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(data.data) //<---- this should be data.data
        link.download = true;
        link.href = url;
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log('We were not able to complete your request.');
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to gdh, when using URL.createObjectURL() make sure to do URL.revokeObjectURL() in order to make sure there are no memory leaks. This helps the case of when apps are running long times without any reloads occuring. Referrence to this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

check the memory management section.